# Set /etc/hosts for each vagrant vm by ansible

Tags: deployment, vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile, ansible-2.x

## My Vagrantfile

```
hosts = {
    "host01" => "192.168.11.101",
    "host02" => "192.168.11.102",
}

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.ssh.username = "root"
    config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
    config.ssh.insert_key = "true"

    hosts.each_with_index do |(name,ip),index|
        config.vm.define name do |machine|
            machine.vm.box = "centos7"
            machine.vm.box_check_update = false
            machine.vm.hostname = name


            machine.vm.synced_folder "/data", "/data"

            machine.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip

            machine.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
                v.name = name
                v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2048]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

## ansible tamplate for generate /etc/host

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_' + iface].ipv4.address }}  {{ host }}
{% endfor %}
```

## ansible task

```
- name: Create the hosts file for all machines
  template: src=hosts.j2 dest=/etc/hosts
```

## But I get the result

```
[root@host01 ~]# cat /etc/hosts  
127.0.0.1 localhost              
10.0.2.15  host01                
10.0.2.15  host02
```

## ifconfig

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500                     
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0                   
        inet6 fe80::42:49ff:fed1:eebb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>           
        ether 02:42:49:d1:ee:bb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)                         
        RX packets 77  bytes 6065 (5.9 KiB)                                       
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0                               
        TX packets 99  bytes 8572 (8.3 KiB)                                       
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0                

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500                      
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255               
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fede:e0e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>           
        ether 08:00:27:de:0e:0e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)                      
        RX packets 785483  bytes 57738892 (55.0 MiB)                              
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0                               
        TX packets 777457  bytes 1957320412 (1.8 GiB)                             
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0                

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500                      
        inet 192.168.11.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.11.255      
        ether 08:00:27:15:2c:64  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)                      
        RX packets 41445  bytes 39878552 (38.0 MiB)                               
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0                               
        TX packets 18055  bytes 2113498 (2.0 MiB)
```

I found in `ifconfig`, only `enp0s8 inet 192.168.11.102`  is different on host01 and host02

---

host01 and host02  got same ip ??

host01  has a docker registry.

- host01,  `curl http://host01:5006/v2/_catalog`  works
- host02,  `curl http://host01:5006/v2/_catalog`  not work

Answer (score 1):

> host01 and host02 got same ip ??

Yes. That's how Vagrant works and is able to connect for orchestration purposes to machines created from a variety of boxes coming from different publishers.

There's nothing strange about that, they are connected to different virtual switches in VirtualBox.

> I just want host01 and host02 can access each other by hostname .

Use the other interface as the value of `iface` in your Jinja2 template (you did not show it in the question anyway).

Comment: I update the ifconfig in question, do you mean that ?

Comment: I am not familiar with ansible template variable , that code is copied from a gist.  What is the `second interface as the value of iface` ?  Is it the one ifconfig enp0s8  ?

Comment: You have `'ansible_' + iface` in your template. Assign appropriate value to `iface`. I don't know what it is. You are sitting in front of your computer. Display the facts with `debug` and copy-paste the interface name. I also don't know where to. Use `grep` to locate where you set the value.

Comment: You are right, `grep -RH ansible_default_ipv4` find `iface` is set in `group_vars/all`, Its  value is `ansible_default_ipv4.interface` . Google this just come up a lot of questions.  Is there any doc about how to use this variable,  Such as refer second interface by `ansible_default_ipv4.interface[1]`?

Comment: Execute it against the proper target. Sorry, I'm not going to guide you what keys to press on your keyboard and this is what you currently demand. Please deal with it yourself. I only answered the question you asked.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help.Though ansible's doc is too huge,  I think I need read more about it..